# Is there any way to skip the start menu and go straight to the desktop (without disabling Modern UI)?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I have Windows 8 go to the desktop by default?](https://superuser.com/questions/395819/how-can-i-have-windows-8-go-to-the-desktop-by-default)

I'm not looking to disable the modern UI, I just want to go straight to the desktop after logging in, rather than the Start menu screen.  Is this possible?

Again, **I do not want to disable/replace the modern UI**.  I just want to be able to see the desktop immediately upon login.

To clarify, the main use case I have right now is automation clients connected to a KVM.  We can auto-login, but seeing the modern UI when I toggle the KVM to the Windows 8 systems is not very useful as I want to see what's running on the desktop.  We disable auto-locking, so the fact that the systems would go back to the modern UI is not an issue.  I just want to be able to see the desktop without having to interact with a keyboard/mouse on the KVM/system.

Because we want to test our software on Windows 8, we don't want to disable the Modern UI (which most client systems will probably be running), and ideally, would like to avoid third party software, staying reasonably close to a default Windows installation.

Comment: Pressing Esc key or clicking the Desktop live tile is too much for you, eh?

Comment: @Mufasa The main use case right now is for some automation clients, where we want to be able to see what's running on the desktop, ideally just by toggling the KVM display.  Note we want to keep the modern UI, we just want to get to the desktop by default.

Comment: @Moab - as stayed in the first part of my question, I'm not looking to turn off the Modern UI; in fact, I want to keep the Modern UI, I just want to get straight to the desktop.  I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: @mufasa please vote to reopen if you feel that way.  Thanks!

Comment: I would vote to reopen, but don't have the rep on this SE site yet. :(  I did flag it though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6310/discussion-between-mufasa-and-ernie)

Comment: Hey Ernie. Do this. Keep your Desktop as the first tile on the Start screen and see if you can write a script which simulates pressing the `Enter` key as soon as you log in. In Start, pressing Enter opens the first app on the screen. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this app to help you: [RetroUI](http://retroui.com/)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [RetroUI](http://retroui.com/), you can also use 3rd party Start Menu apps that include an option to bypass/skip the Windows 8 Start Screen and log in straight to the desktop:

- [Start8](http://www.stardock.com/products/start8/index.asp)

  > Boot directly to the Windows 8 desktop
- [Pokki](https://www.pokki.com/windows-8-start-menu)

  > Boot to the desktop and skip the Windows 8 Start Screen
- [Wentutu](http://www.wentutu.com/windows8startmenu.html)

  > Users can boot directly to the desktop mode automatically and skip Start screen of Windows 8