# Windows 10: How to boot straight to desktop without ever seeing the "logging you now in" screen?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, login-screen, auto-login

How to boot *STRAIGHT* to the desktop on Windows 10 WITHOUT ever seeing the "Logging you now in" screen?

This [link](http://www.itproportal.com/2015/02/09/get-rid-microsoft-windows-10s-login-screen/) removes the necessity for the password authenticication (check!)
This [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3er06p/how_to_disable_welcome_screen/) for Win8 disables showing the login (check! but nothing changes on Win10!)

When Windows 10 boots, I still see twice (2 second counts) showing the login screen once (static background below) then automatically logging me in with the round "in progresss" circle dots animation.

That means screen fading effect from black "dos" into this useless screen, then fade out, and fading back in to the loading of the destop which all togeher takes 2 seconds and oh so ugly.

How to bypass seeing the login screens all together and going straight from the black dos screen to the desktop?

Bottom line: I don't want to ever see the logging screen during post! But how? Any ideas or suggestions are welcome and highly appreciated. PS I dont want to use hacky third party programs, just in-Windows-10-solutions please that are safe and built in.

### [image]

*Before you start complaining about duplicate post, do your research!

Entirely different [topic](https://superuser.com/questions/498507/is-there-any-way-to-skip-the-start-menu-and-go-straight-to-the-desktop-without) about the start menu

Entirely different [topic](https://superuser.com/questions/395819/how-can-i-have-windows-8-go-to-the-desktop-by-default) for Windows 8 about skipping the GUI tiles*
***Nothing I have found online has solved my question!***

Comment: I'm confused about your motive, is it because of its ugliness and 2 seconds of loading?

Comment: Thanks @Cosco Tech for your question, I will clarify my motiv further: its because of its uselessness of the 2 second fade-in-and-fade-out waste that I just dont need to see! Even not if the background would be a beautifull sea mermaid of my dreams ;) I still want to skip this entirely useless part alltogether and boot directly into my desktop, lowering the whole bootprocess from 3 seconds to an stonishing 1 second boottime on my dual M.2 PCIE NVMe Raid 0 ssd configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a tablet, press and hold the tablet mode. A box will pop up that says go to settings.  It's self-explanatory from there.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Welcome to superuser: While this may or may not answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation and detail on how to do something with as easy to follow instructions. If you feel your answer is correct do these things and reedit. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Comment: No tablet! Standard DESKTOP computer with motherboard, cpu, ram, psu, ssd, hdd, gpu, wifi, utp lan, etc with Win7 64bit EN Professional.

Comment: Type "msconfig" in the Run box, and in the Boot tab, check the "no GUI" box. That's for the screens that appear prior to your logon screen. If you want that one to be skipped also, I'm afraid that's not possible, but you can avoid having to enter your password by typing "netplwiz" in the Run box, and uncheck the "Users must enter a password" box, enter and confirm your user password, click OK, and you're done. Not sure that's entirely what you wanted, though... EDIT: since you can choose the picture for your logon screen now, pick one solid black in Settings.