# Automatically switch to Desktop after log-in in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

Is it possible to **automatically** log you into classic Windows desktop in Windows 8.1?

Either with Windows settings or by using 3rd party software..

This is pretty important for me since I don't know if I should buy this OS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to boot to the desktop in Windows 8.1?](http://superuser.com/questions/661330/how-to-boot-to-the-desktop-in-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the Desktop, then right-click in the taskbar, and select “Properties”, then click on the navigation tab to open up a menu. Check the box in the Start Screen list that says “Go to the desktop instead of Start when I sign in”.  Then click the “OK” button.

[image]

Next time you start up you’ll go to the desktop first.

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mis_laboratory/archive/2013/08/09/windows-8-1-boot-to-desktop-maybe-the-designers-were-right.aspx

Comment: I select your option because of the screen shot. very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

From Microsoft's "[What's New in Windows 8.1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn140266.aspx)":

> **Boot to Desktop**
>
> We have made configuration options available which will allow you to
>   boot directly to the desktop in Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible in Windows 8.1

Refer to the following links for steps on how to do this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mis_laboratory/archive/2013/08/09/windows-8-1-boot-to-desktop-maybe-the-designers-were-right.aspx

http://www.pcworld.com/article/2043243/how-to-boot-to-desktop-mode-in-windows-8-1.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! We don't encourage link-only answers here (what happens if the link rots?), could you edit your answer to summarize the linked resources?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 8, you can go straight to the desktop [as detailed in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/561286/85121).  Windows 8.1 has an option to go straight to the desktop.

Note that this doesn't eliminate the start screen, just skips it on logon.