# How to boot to the desktop in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, modern-ui

I just installed Windows 8.1, but I can't locate the setting to disable the Metro start screen, and boot directly to the desktop instead.

So how do you configure Windows 8.1 to boot straight to the desktop?

Comment: You should update the title of the question to better reflect you want to boot directly to the desktop because its not possible to "disable" the Modern UI/Start Screen/Metro interface.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- Right-click on the Windows 8.1 taskbar, then choose Properties.
- Click on the Navigation tab, then under the Start screen section, check the box next to "Go to the desktop instead of Start when I sign in."

Comment: For completeness, if you literally have to boot to the desktop without user intervention you may also have to [skip the login screen](http://superuser.com/q/405941).

Answer (score 9):

Just right-click on the taskbar and head to **Properties → Navigation → When I sign in or close all apps on a screen**, go to the desktop instead of Start. This will also bring you back to the desktop whenever you close a Modern app, which is handy if you use one every once in awhile.